# Как получить значение pk в generic class based views?

Tags: django

При создании блога появилась необходимость выводить в каждой категории соответствующие посты, используя обычную функцию проблем не возникает, но насколько я понимаю это не совсем продвинутый способ, хотя в данный момент он выполняет задачу, все же хочу узнать как сделать тоже самое используя встроенные классы путем их наследования. Если конкретно, как передать посты связанные с определенной категорией ( pk  категории извлечь из регулярного выражения в  URLs.py )в шаблон а не все сразу? Django 1.10

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'), 
]
```

views.py:

```
class CategoryView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'blog/category.html'
    model = Category


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'
    model = Post
```

Вообщем вот как-то так. Я что-то упускаю и не могу понять что.

Comment: Выложите хотя бы часть кода, который нужно модифицировать, так как у меня ответ касается в банальном прописывании фильтрации в get_queryset().

Comment: Добавил пример кода, над этим банальным я и бьюсь. Так как не знаю как отфильтровать, поскольку не могу получить значение pk из urls.py которое передается из строки браузера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю из шаблона url, значение 123 из, например, http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/category/123, заносится в справочник kwargs.
У меня подобный вопрос решался этим:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Subcategory.objects.filter(category=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

**self.kwargs['pk'] забирает значение 123.**

Насчет регулярного выражения, точно не знаю, но вроде бы нужно поправить:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$') ---> url(r'^(?P<pk>[\d]+)$')
```